# not getting any compilation error, however, neither getting any output as well

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub dowhileloop()

Dim x As Long
Dim sumX As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test data")

For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
sumX = ws.Cells(x, 5).Value2
n = 1

If ws.Cells(x, 2) = ws.Cells(x + n, 2) And ws.Cells(x, 4) = ws.Cells(x + n, 
4) Then
    sumX = sumX + ws.Cells(x + n, 5).Value
    ws.Cells(x + n, 6) = sumX
Else
    n = n + 1

End If
Next x

End Sub
```

The logic I am using is not correct to get the Output I want. This is the first time I am writing a VBA.

Please suggest on it.

Comment: I can't see that you're putting any values back on the sheet.  Somewhere you'll need something like `ws.Cells(x + n, 5) = sumX`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It worked, I am getting the output, however it is just multiplying the column by 2, mayb the logic I used is not working.

Can you see the image I have attached with the question, it shows what output I want

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your image - is Input/Output on the same sheet?  Is it showing columns A:E with column C mostly black?

Comment: sorry for that,

1. the output we can keep on the other sheet( sheet 2)
2. I kept column C black because we do not need it

Comment: Your example output is a Pivot of the example input, with 'Repeat all item labels' on - is there any reason you're reinventing the wheel to create something Excel can do automatically?

Comment: Yes, there is the need because I want the output in the exactly same column order as we have to upload this file directly to the software, so the column order has to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I can see is that you don't put the values back on the sheet, as mentioned in my first comment.
Maybe after your `End If` you need something like:
`ws.Cells(x,2) = sumX`

The logic in your loop is also incorrect.  As far as I can see this is what it's doing:

**Loop 1**
`x` = 2
`sumX` = 78  (cells (2, 5) = range E2)
`n` = 0

Using these values your IF condition is stating:

```
If cell B2 = cell B2 AND cell D2 = cell D2 then  <this is always true>
     sumX = 78 + 78
else
     n = 1
end if
```

As the condition is true then `n` hasn't increased, so loop 2 is stating:

```
   sumX = 64
   If cell B3 = cell B3 and cell D3 = cell D3 then <again true>
        sumX = 64 + 64
   else
        n = n +1
   end if
```

Maybe use `n=1` before your loop?